# How to update only matching columns in db2

Tags: sql, database, db2, sql-update

I'm trying to do an update query that looks like this:

```
update semester_workload tA
set tA.working = (SELECT DEPUTAT_WS11 from TD_DOZENTEN t1 where t1.Pruefernummer = tA.ID_Lecturer AND tA.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS11')
```

but db2 automatically updates the whole column instead of only the data that matches the "where" statement.

How can I make it to only update the data I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to put the logic in the `where`:

```
update semester_workload tA
    set tA.working = (select DEPUTAT_WS11 
                      from TD_DOZENTEN t1
                      where t1.Pruefernummer = tA.ID_Lecturer AND tA.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS11')
    where exists (select 1
                  from TD_DOZENTEN t1
                  where t1.Pruefernummer = tA.ID_Lecturer AND tA.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS11'
                 );
```

I don't think that DB2 supports either `JOIN` or `FROM` in an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Yep, that worked, thanks! I'll verify as soon as I can

Comment: not necessary to have "AND tA.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS11'" into subselect ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it

```
UPDATE semester_workload t0
SET t0.working = 
(
    SELECT t1.DEPUTAT_WS11 FROM TD_DOZENTEN t1 
    WHERE t1.Pruefernummer = t0.ID_Lecturer
)
where t0.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS11' and exists 
(
    SELECT * FROM TD_DOZENTEN t1 
    WHERE t1.Pruefernummer = t0.ID_Lecturer
)
```